Exterior algebra and space of spinors
The approach I am used to define spinors in arbitrary dimensions is based on finding a matrix representation of the Clifford algebra $$\Gamma_a\Gamma_b+\Gamma_b\Gamma_a = 2\delta_{ab}\mathbf{1}\tag{1}.$$
Then it turns out that one can find representations in terms of $2^n\times 2^n$ matrices. These in turn naturally act on $2^{n}$-dimensional column vectors. Moreover, we can use these matrices to construct $$\Sigma_{ab}=\frac{1}{4}[\Gamma_a,\Gamma_b]\tag{2}$$
and the metrics $\Sigma_{ab}$ can be shown to furnish a set of generators for a representation of $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$. Therefore these row vectors together with the associated $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$ representation are spinors in $2n$-dimensions.
It turns out that there seems to be another approach based on the Clifford algebra ${\rm Cl}(V,Q)$ and Exterior Algebra $\Lambda(V)$ of a vector space.
More precisely, let $V$ have dimension $2n$. Let $V_n$ be a totally-isotropic subspace of dimension $n$ and let $V_n^\ast$ be its dual. Then we can decompose $$V=V_n\oplus V_n^\ast.$$
The inner product $Q$ then acts as $$Q(v_1+\omega_1,v_2+\omega_2)=\omega_1(v_2)+\omega_2(v_1).$$
Then it is said that the exterior algebra $\Lambda_n=\Lambda(V_n)$ carries an irreducible representation of ${\rm Cl}(V,Q)$ generated by $$\Gamma_{(v,\omega)}\mu = v\wedge\mu + \omega \lrcorner \mu.$$
The elements of $\Lambda_n$ are then called spinors. Moreover, it is said they transform reducibly under ${\rm Spin}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ and that the even and odd parts of the exterior algebra $\Lambda_n$ provide the irreducible spinors.
I am very confused about how the two approaches are related. I am quite sure they are the same, and most certainly the vector space on which the matrices $\Gamma_a$ is probably $\Lambda_n$ after fixing some basis.
So how does that work? How these two approaches to spinor relate and how can we see that the first one is just the second one in disguise after choosing a basis?

Should be $V = V_n\oplus V_n^*$, not $\otimes$.

Also worth noting that $Q$ must be split/metabolic/hyperbolic/whatever your favorite terminology is.

Well, for starters, $\Lambda(V_n)$ has dimension $2^n$. You can write down a basis in terms of wedge products of a basis of $V_n$. This surely must be what the first approach is doing.

@NicholasTodoroff, the tensor product was a typo, I corrected it for the direct sum. Thanks for pointing it out!

@QiaochuYuan so the point would be that we choose a basis ${e_a}$ of $V_n$ with dual basis $\theta^a$. Then we have linear operators $\Gamma_{e_a}$ and $\Gamma_{\theta^a}$ acting on $\Lambda(V_n)$. If we further use the basis ${e_{a_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{a_k} : 0\leq k \leq n}$ for $\Lambda(V_n)$ then the matrices of these linear operators should be the $\Gamma_a$ matrices of the first approach and the column vectors with $2^n$ components representing spinors in that approach should be the expression of elements of $\Lambda(V_n)$ in this basis?

@Gold: that's how I'm guessing the first approach works, yes.

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}\newcommand\lintr{\mathbin\lrcorner}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
$They seem to be the same (assuming you're referring to the complex algebra generated by the gamma matrices).
$\mathrm{Cl}(V,Q)\cong\Ext V$ as vector spaces, and this isomorphism is natural. One way to construct it is with the generators: simply use an orthonormal basis $e_1,\dotsc, e_{2n}$ of $V$ (which corresponds to the gamma matrices) to send $e_{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_{i_k}$ to the Clifford product $e_{i_1}\dotsb e_{i_k}$ when $i_1,\dotsc,i_k$ are all distinct. Under this isomorphism, for any $v\in V$ and $X\in\mathrm{Cl}(V,Q)\cong\Ext V$ we have $$vX = v\wedge X + v\lcontr X$$ where the second operation is the interior product raised with the metric $Q$.
Now if $X$ is in the subalgebra generated by $V_n$ (naturally isomorphic to $\Ext V_n$ as algebras, not just as vector spaces) and $v = v' + \omega$ for $v'\in V_n$ and $\omega\in V_n^*$, $$(v'+\omega)X = v'\wedge X + \omega\lcontr X + \omega\wedge X.$$ The product $v'\lcontr X = 0$ because both $v'$ and $X$ are in $\Ext V_n$. We also have $\omega\lcontr X = \omega\lintr X$. The only thing left is the pesky term $\omega\wedge X$.
But we want $2^n{\times}2^n$ matrices acting on $2^n$ column vectors; this corresponds exactly to something operating on $\Ext V_n$ that returns something in the same subalgebra. We can do this.
Let $I = e_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_n$ where $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is a basis for $V_n$; there is a corresponding dual basis $e^1,\dotsc,e^n$ of $V_n^*$ and we define $I^* = e^n\wedge\dotsb\wedge e^1$. Now
$$
  \form X_{V_n} := (X\lcontr I^*)\lcontr I
$$
is exactly a projection onto $\Ext V_n$. So we have an action of $\mathrm{Cl}(V,Q)$ on $X\in\Ext V_n$ given by
$$
  v.X := \form{vX}_{V_n} = v'\wedge X + \omega\lintr X.
$$
I suspect this is what the gamma matrices are doing to column vectors.

Now I think I understand how to connect the two approaches. Firstly let us remind how people construct the matrices in the first approach. The basic observation is that if we define
$$b_a^+ = \frac{1}{2}(\Gamma_a+i\Gamma_{n+a}),\quad b_a^-=\frac{1}{2}(\Gamma_a-i\Gamma_{n+a}),\tag{1}$$
then the anti-commutation relations obeyed by the $\Gamma_a$ are equivalent to $$\{b_a^-,b_a^+\}=\delta_{ab}\tag{2}.$$
We can realize these explicitly in a vector space with basis $\{\Phi_{\alpha_1\dots \alpha_n} : \alpha_i = \pm 1\}$, where the action of the $b_a^\pm$ are explicitly
$$b_i^s\Phi_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_{i-1}\alpha_i \alpha_{i+1}\cdots \alpha_n} =\delta_{s,-\alpha_i}\Phi_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_{i-1} s\alpha_{i+1}\cdots \alpha_n}.\tag{3}$$
In short $b_i^+$ changes $\alpha_i=-1$ to $\alpha_i=+1$ and kills off $\alpha_i=+1$ while $b_i^-$ changes $\alpha_i=+1$ to $\alpha_i=-1$ and kills off $\alpha_i=-1$.
Clearly there are $2^n$ elements in this basis and therefore the linear operators act on $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$. From that one can use (1) again to invert and define the $\Gamma_a$ and check they obey the right commutation relations.
Now let us see how the second approach actually just makes this one a tiny bit more geometric and concrete by giving explicitly a vector space with such a basis. Let $\{e_a\}$ be a basis of $V_n$ and $\{\theta^a\}$ the dual basis. If $X\in V$ we know that $\Gamma_X$ is a representation of the Clifford algebra. As a result it must be the case that
$$\Gamma_{e^a}\Gamma_{\theta^b}+\Gamma_{\theta^b}\Gamma_{e_a} = 2Q(e_a,\theta^b)=2\theta^b(e_a).\tag{4}$$
As a result, we should really be identifying $$b_a^+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Gamma_{e_a},\quad b_a^- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Gamma_{\theta^a}.\tag{5}$$
Moreover, the way the representation acts confirms this is the case. If we pick $e_{a_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{a_k}$ we can imagine this being $\Phi_{\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n}$ where $\alpha_i =+1$ if $i\in\{a_1,\dots, a_k\}$ and $\alpha_i=-1$ if $i\notin \{a_1,\dots, a_k\}$. In other words, $e_{a_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{a_k}$ has $k$ plus signs and $n-k$ minus signs. We can therefore say that $\Phi_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_n}$ represents a wedge product of the basis elements of $V_n$ where $e_i$ appears if $\alpha_i=+1$ and it doesn't when $\alpha_i=-1$.
Then we see that the fact that $\Gamma_{e_a}e_{a_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{a_k} = e_a\wedge e_{a_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{a_k}$ confirms this: the action of $b_a^+$ flips a minus to plus by adding a vector if it wasn't there, and kills of a minus if the vector was there. Likewise $\Gamma_{\theta^a}e_{a_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{a_k} = \theta^a\lrcorner e_{a_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{a_k}$ acts like $b_a^-$, it flips a plus to minus by removing a vector if it was there and annihilating the product if the vector was not there.
From this it follows that the gamma matrices of the first approach are obtained from these operators inverting (1) again.
